# php: reverse Country Calling Code lookup

Tags: php

I am using `php` to process a list of telephone numbers in international format, ie:

```
00261320441680
```

Is there any existing library in `php` that I could use to get the corresponding country code, for a given telephone number ?

If not, what would be the easiest way for me to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library exists that will parse a string of digits and reformat it to international standards (a number like 4402081231234 to '+44 20 8123 1234'). It will also return the Phone Number region, 'GB' or 'US' from a number, if there is the country code embedded in the number.

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber The original library is in Java, but there are also versions in Javascript, Python, Ruby and PHP, among others.